# How to Count records in a related table and allow user to override

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom field on the CRActivity table in which I need to store the number of records in a related table.  I am trying to set the field to the value when screen CR306030 opens.  The user needs to be able to override the calculated number so, I'm thinking that I need logic on the calculation to check if the custom field is > 0, in which case, don't populate the custom field and assume it's already been set.

Previously, I've tried to do this in the Field_Selecting events but, this is not working.  I'm thinking I might be able to use a PXFormula attribute.  Any suggestions?

I tried making a custom attribute which is close but, it won't save the values to the db.  The save button enables, I can click it and it looks like it saves but, no dice.  Some mundane detail, I'm sure.....

Here's my custom attribute:

```
public class CFCountIfZeroAttribute : PXIntAttribute
{
    public override void FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null)
            return;

        CRActivity activity = (CRActivity)e.Row;
        CRActivityExt activityExt = activity.GetExtension<CRActivityExt>();
        if (activityExt.usrCustomField <= 0)
        {
                int aggregateValue = BQLToFind();
                e.ReturnValue = aggregateValue;
                cache.SetValue<CRActivityExt.usrCustomField>(e.Row, aggregateValue);
                cache.IsDirty = true;

        }
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever done a count within a PXFormula, but what if you created a custom attribute?

```
[DBUIInt()]
[EditableCount()]
public virtual int? CountField
```

---

```
public class EditableCountAttribute
{
    public override void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row != null)
        {
            //if CountField is 0, lookup the count from another table
        }
    }
}
```

This is just off the top of my head. You could pass the field you're counting into the attribute if you wanted to do this elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I do need the aggregation on two screens now so, I custom attribute is definitely the way to go but, I can't get the value to save to the db.  I put my code in my original post.